# Updating post data on save (save_post vs wp_insert_post_data)

Tags: posts, plugin-development, hooks, save-post, escaping

I am trying to modify post data on post save action.

Firstly I tried to use `save_post` hook like that

```
function post_save_action($post_id, $post, $update)
    {
        if ($this->is_temp_saving_post($post, $post_id)) {
            return;
        }
        // Check user permissions
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
            return;
        // Update post
        if (!$this->is_proper_post_type($post)) {
            return;
        }
        $processed_content = $this->process_post_data($post);
        $update_data = [
            self::POST_ID => $post_id,
            self::POST_CONTENT => $processed_content
        ];
        // Prevent infinite loop
        remove_action('save_post', array($this, 'post_save_action'), 99);
        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post($update_data);
        // Add hook again
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'post_save_action'), 99);
    }
```

The problem here is that `wp_update_post($update_data);` triggers `save_post` action again for other plugins, so all plugins except mine are being executed twice, and that is bad.

Then I found another hook `wp_insert_post_data` and add my processing logic

```
public function post_insert_filter($data, $postattr)
    {
        $post_id = $postattr['ID'];
        $post_object = $this->convertToObject($data);
        $post_object->ID = $post_id;
        if ($this->is_temp_saving_post($post_object, $post_id)) {
            return $data;
        }
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $data;
        }
        // Update post
        if (!$this->is_proper_post_type($post_object)) {
            return $data;
        }
        $processed_content = $this->process_post_data($post_object);
        $data[self::POST_CONTENT] = $processed_content;
        return $data;
    }
```

It works hook is not called twice, but the problem for the time `wp_insert_post_data` is triggerd, data already has been escaped(parentheses) somewhere, but I need raw data here.

Please suggest the right way to modify data considering all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, Data was sanitized [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) (line 2997).

If you don't want any plugin/theme run on action `save_post`. User  function `remove_all_actions` to remove all functions hooked to action `save_post`.

```
function post_save_action($post_id, $post, $update)
 {
    if ($this->is_temp_saving_post($post, $post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    // Check user permissions
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;
    // Update post
    if (!$this->is_proper_post_type($post)) {
        return;
    }
    $processed_content = $this->process_post_data($post);
    $update_data = [
        self::POST_ID => $post_id,
        self::POST_CONTENT => $processed_content
    ];
    // Backup actions
    global $wp_filter, $merged_filters;
    $backup_wp_filter = $wp_filter;
    $backup_merged_filters = $merged_filters;
    // Remove all functions which hooked to this action, to prevent run twice.
    remove_all_actions('save_post');
    // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post($update_data);
   // restore actions
    $wp_filter = $backup_wp_filter;
    $merged_filters = $backup_merged_filters;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works, but maybe there are other ways. Because I fill little bit confused about backing up global variables, this may change in wordpress core and this won't work.

Comment: it's global vars, used in a lot of core functions, I don't think it will be changed in short term. :)